# How to decrypt and verify integrity token?

Tags: android, magento, google-play

We are implementing Play Integrity API in Android using magento backend.is there any example or tutorial available how to integrity token connect with (Play integrity) token Decode in magento.here is the demo is available in node js.

Demo for Node js->https://github.com/1nikolas/play-integrity-checker-server

How we same  this implement in magento?